# html5 canvas display shapes based on radio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I would like to display one shapes at a time,
I'm having trouble how to remove the chosen radio.

```js
 function display() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('displaycake_sketch');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    //context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.beginPath();

    if (document.getElementById('color1').checked) {
      context.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
    } else if (document.getElementById('color2').checked) {
      context.strokeStyle = "#0000FF";
    }
    if (document.getElementById('shape1').checked) {
      context.arc(95, 50, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      context.stroke();
    }

    if (document.getElementById('shape2').checked) {
      context.rect(50, 27, 50, 100);
      context.stroke();
    }
  }


  $(function() {
    var drawObject = $('#displaycake_sketch').sketch();
    var oldRedraw = drawObject.data('sketch').redraw;
    drawObject.data('sketch').redraw = function() {
      oldRedraw.call(this);
      display();
    }
    $(".tools a").eq(0).attr("style", "color:#fba557");
    $(".tools a").click(function() {
      $(".tools a").removeAttr("style");
      $(this).attr("style", "color:#000");
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/lib/sketch.js"></script>

   
<canvas id="displaycake_sketch"></canvas>
<div> <input type="radio" id="shape1" name="shape_design" value="CIRCLE" onchange="display()"/> O 
<input type="radio" id="shape2" name="shape_design" value="RECTANGLE" onchange="display()"/> [] </div>

<div> <input type="radio" id="color1" name="color_design" value="RED" onchange="display()"/> RED  
<input type="radio" id="color2" name="color_design" value="BLUE" onchange="display()"/> BLUE </div>

<div class="tools"> 
<a href="#displaycake_sketch" class="btn btn-primary" data-tool="marker"> Marker</a> 
<a href="#displaycake_sketch" class="btn btn-primary" data-tool="eraser"> Eraser</a>

</div>
```

I'm fine with the free draw (sketch thingy), but just the display of the shapes...

Hope somebody could help me... I'm getting confused all these codes that I've got from different sources. Thank you in advance..

Comment: the `//context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);` is in comment while it does solve your problem (I think ...). What that statement does is clearing your canvas (so that it becomes empty).

Comment: @KarelG I did comment it out because the sketch /doodle part (marker) it won't appear.

Answer (score 0):

Add `context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);` to clear the canvas before drawing a new shape

```js
function display() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('displaycake_sketch');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    //context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.beginPath();
  
    if (document.getElementById('color1').checked) {
      context.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
    } else if (document.getElementById('color2').checked) {
      context.strokeStyle = "#0000FF";
    }
  }
  
function drawShape() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('displaycake_sketch');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    //context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.beginPath();
    
    if (document.getElementById('shape1').checked) {
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      context.arc(95, 50, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      context.stroke();
    }

    if (document.getElementById('shape2').checked) {
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      context.rect(50, 27, 50, 100);
      context.stroke();
    }
}

 $(function() {
    var drawObject = $('#displaycake_sketch').sketch();
    var oldRedraw = drawObject.data('sketch').redraw;
    drawObject.data('sketch').redraw = function() {
      oldRedraw.call(this);
    }
    $(".tools a").eq(0).attr("style", "color:#fba557");
    $(".tools a").click(function() {
      $(".tools a").removeAttr("style");
      $(this).attr("style", "color:#000");
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/lib/sketch.js"></script>

   
<canvas id="displaycake_sketch"></canvas>
<div> <input type="radio" id="shape1" name="shape_design" value="CIRCLE" onchange="drawShape()"/> O 
<input type="radio" id="shape2" name="shape_design" value="RECTANGLE" onchange="drawShape()"/> [] </div>

<div> <input type="radio" id="color1" name="color_design" value="RED" onchange="display()"/> RED  
<input type="radio" id="color2" name="color_design" value="BLUE" onchange="display()"/> BLUE </div>

<div class="tools"> 
<a href="#displaycake_sketch" class="btn btn-primary" data-tool="marker"> Marker</a> 
<a href="#displaycake_sketch" class="btn btn-primary" data-tool="eraser"> Eraser</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it got a lot of bugs. I really wanted to display the shapes depending on the radio. At the same time I can doodle around the shape. E.g. when i choose circle - I can doodle around it.  Then when I choose rectangle, the circle will disappear but the doodle will maintain.